# Securely store access token in Cordova

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage

**Edit:** *see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36480620/999516) for the solution*

Currently working on a Hybrid App with [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) where there is a requirement to store an authentication Token in order to keep the user logged in, and also guarantee that this data cannot be accessed outside  the App context.

There is of course plenty of solutions for this task, each one with different pros-and-cons so it's confusing (for me) to locate the one technology that fits.

I've been looking at [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage) and other candidates:

---

### LocalStorage

- Obvious choice for small data.
- Data gets wiped in `iOS` when the system is low on memory.

### IndexedDB

- Buggy support in `iOS` ([IndexedDB support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb))

### WebSQL (SQLite)

- Apparently a good option for small data and decent support ([WebSQL suppport](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage)) but it's deprecated.

### SQLite

- There are related issues with `Cordova` in `iOS`.

### LokiJS

- Looks like an overkill for this scenario but is definitely a strong candidate. Is the any security concerns I should be aware of (as I read it  locally persist data to `JSON` files)?

## PouchDB + SQLite

- Well, it's a JS client to work with CouchDB or Couchbase databases wich can also work with SQLite but again I only need to store a Token..

---

So apparently the best option for Android/iOS cross-compatibility should ironically be WebSQL, but is no longer being developed and I have to guarantee long-term support.

So my question is: are there any other options I'm missing to securely store an access Token? If don't, wich of the above ones should be the best choice for this task?

Comment: I know this has been answered but LokiJS has a cryptoFsAdapter that store s the JSON encrypted.

Comment: @JoeMinichino Thank you, i will take a look into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some research I will share my conclusion.

Funny enough, none of the above candidates are suitable for **securely** storing an access Token. The approach should be using a native solution for both Android (*Shared Preferences*) and iOS (*Keychain*).

In the particular case of Ionic, a [broadcaster plugin](https://github.com/bsorrentino/cordova-broadcaster) for Cordova could be used to communicate JS with Native so you can access the stored data.

Comment: Thanks, this post doesn't have the attention it needs.

Would be great if you could explain a little bit more on how to save and retrieve data from the Android (Shared Preferences) and iOS (Keychain). I can't find good guides!

Comment: to answer WHY NOT SECURE - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144414/how-secure-is-storing-data-with-localstorage

Comment: to answer WHAT TO USE INSTEAD (didnt check) - https://github.com/pradeep1991singh/cordova-plugin-secure-key-store

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage

Answer (score 1):

The only secure way is using "httponly cookie". However, since april 2020 Apple uses wkwebview which has cookie problem.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is the best option to go with as the content of DB will be encrypted and saved. Also native apps rely on SQLite to save data. 
To make CRUD easier with SQLite, I have created a wrapper library. Please check it [here](https://github.com/sesubash/cordova-sqlite-wrapper)

Comment: As far as I know SQLite can be encrypted, but you have to expose the password hardcoded somewhere in the client code.

Answer (score -3):

Go for LocalStorage, it is the best way to store

Comment: As I commented, LocalStorage gets wiped on iOS when low memory.

Comment: and possibly not secured to store `access_token` and/or `refresh_token` locally in the app.

Comment: LocalStorage alone will not make the tokens *secure*